# Extracting values from a deeply nested data structure in haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, immutability

I've been trying to work out how to use the language-bash package to parse some simple bash scripts, and I've come across the following structure

```hs
Right (List [Statement (Last (Pipeline {timed = False, timedPosix = False, inverted = False, commands = [Command (SimpleCommand [Assign (Parameter "x" Nothing) Equals (RValue [Char '3'])] []) []]})) Sequential])
```

as a result of running

```hs
import Language.Bash.Parse
parse "" "x=3"
```

I could theoretically just pattern match the whole thing away, though I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of accessing the values of the Assign datatype ('x', (Char '3').

Is there anyway to cleanly access those values (or generally access values in a complex datastructure) without obsessive pattern matching ?

Comment: Probably not. I don't see anything interesting in the package, and `parse` doesn't simplify the data structure if, as in this case, your entire script consists of just a single assignment word, rather than a mix of lists, pipelines, compound commands, etc.

Comment: You might be able to do something with lenses, but I don't think that would be all that clearer than pattern matching.

Comment: Lenses should be quite a lot cleaner in my opinion, but it's a lot of machinery to involve just for this, and the type errors you get when misusing lenses are famously unfathomable unless you already have some understanding of how lenses work.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

Here's the problem.  You probably want to *either* handle an extremely limited set of possible Bash statements, in which case just writing out the patterns for specific `List` values will be faster than anything else you could possibly do.

*Or,* you want to handle a wide variety of Bash statements, in which case you can't really avoid the functional infrastructure to handle general `List` values.  The same way you'd write an interpreter or compiler for any complex abstract syntax tree, you'll end up more or less writing a function for every (major) type and a case for every constructor.

The main Haskell tools for dealing with big, complex data structures are:

- The "functional infrastructure" described above.  That is, plain old functions defined using pattern matching, that process recursive data structures in a manner that mirrors the structures themselves.  Don't underestimate this approach!  It may seem like a lot of work, but it's likely to lead you to a correct program that handles all well-formed inputs, in a way that *ad hoc* approaches won't.  Start with:

  ```
  {-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

  data M = ... some monad ...
  data Result = ... representation of what you want to extract from the script ...

  processList :: List -> M Result
  ...

  processStatement :: Statement -> M Result
  ...
  ```

  and go from there.  The `-Wall` is important to get the `-Wincomplete-patterns` warning so you don't miss any constructors.
- Lenses, which provide a more ergonomic hierarchical syntax for referring to parts of deeply nested data structures.  Since `bash-language` doesn't provide lenses for these structures, you'd need to write them yourself.  They might allow you to write something along the lines of:

  ```
  lst ^. _Right.statements._head.andOr.pipeline.commands.
         _head._SimpleCommand.assignments._head.parameter.base
  ```

  to extract the `"x"` from `"x=3"`.  Obviously, that doesn't help much, but lenses complement the "functional infrastructure" approach.  The code to actually process all those types is often more easily expressed with lenses than pattern matching.
- Generics, which allow you to generically access certain patterns within recursive data structures, while ignoring the "rest" of the data structure that you don't care about.  The `bash-language` library includes deriving clauses for both `Data` and `Generic` generics. If it didn't, you could use `StandaloneDeriving` clauses to derive them.  As an example, you can use `Data` generics to extract all `Parameter`s from a `List`, regardless of where those `Parameter`s appear, with something like:

  ```
  import Language.Bash.Parse
  import Language.Bash.Word
  import Data.Data
  import Data.Generics.Schemes
  import Data.Generics.Aliases

  parameters :: (Data a) => a -> [Parameter]
  parameters = everything (++) (mkQ [] (\p -> [p]))

  main = do
    let Right lst = parse "" "x=3; y=4; LANG=C echo $x $y"
    print $ parameters lst
  ```

  Here, this prints out a list of all parameters appearing in this shell "script", whether for purposes of assignment or substitution, so it includes:  "x", "y", "LANG", and "x" and "y" again.

  This is a powerful tool, but it's likely to be applicable to only a few specific use-cases.

Ultimately, you'll probably have to take the view that you are writing a Bash interpreter (even if your interpreter does something besides "executing" the Bash script).  Someone's been nice enough to supply a Bash parser to get the input source code into an AST, but the other half of the interpreter -- the actual interpretation itself -- still needs to be written by you.